# Retry with different delay times Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a problem. In my application properties class has different request delay times. The application makes a rest call and waits 30 seconds. If the application gets response == null or == status 5... then the application gets the next delay value, makes a rest call again, and waits 30 seconds. There are different delay values in my `application.yml`. Delay values (second) are 1, 3, 10, 30, 120, 200, 360, 450. How do I solve this problem in Spring? I looked at the documentation in Spring webFlux, but I didn't find a way to change the delay time in runtime.

I thought to use `Retry.backoff`, but I don't how to change the delay time in runtime.

```
WebClient.create()
    .get()
    .uri(GET_STUDENTS_URL)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux(Student.class)
    .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(4, Duration.ofSeconds(3)));
```

Comment: This isn't nearly clear enough. Can you submit your `application.yml`? And, a sample of these bodies you're looking at? If I understand you correctly, the idea is that you get the retry value from the body payload? The server is actually telling you when to retry? And this set is actually a fixed pool of delay values?

Comment: Not this way. I make a rest request and wait for 30 seconds, if the response contains null or the server returned 5... I will put the following value from the config and again make a rest request and wait for 30 seconds. And the call cycle repeats, but with a different time value.

Comment: Ok, this already exists as functionality in `spring-retry` You can roll your own retry logic. And, it uses aspects, so you COULD technically introspect the body payload if that were needed. You still need to update your question to be a lot clearer so people know what you're dealing with concretely

Comment: I'm looking at [Retry.from](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/util/retry/Retry.html#from-java.util.function.Function-) which actually allows you to supply a lambda. I mean, it doesn't get more flexible than that

Answer (score -2):

It seems that you have a challenge in changing the retry delay time in the Retry operation. To change the delay time during runtime, you can use the Retry's backoff function. You can try the following code to achieve this:

```
WebClient.create()
    .get()
    .uri(GET_STUDENTS_URL)
    .retrieve()
    .bodyToFlux(Student.class)
    .retryWhen(Retry.backoff(4, Duration.ofSeconds(timeDelayInSeconds)));
```

In this code, the value of `timeDelayInSeconds` is converted to the required delay time. You can modify it according to your needs.